# How to custom upload component in KendoReacct UI

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui

How can I change the text of the upload component, there is no attribute in api reference to do that.

[This](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/upload/) is the component.

Comment: Welcome! There doesn't appear to be a question here. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation. You can custom render the component. Here is how:

```
 class CustomListItemUI extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { files } = this.props;

        return (

// your custom html
        <ul>
            {
                files.map(file => <li key={file.name}>{file.name}</li>)
            }
        </ul>);
    }
}
```

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/upload/custom-rendering/